# Ruby on Rails: Distinguishing between an upvote and a downvote

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two buttons, one for upvoting and one for downvoting:

```
<%= button_to "+1", { :action => "create", :id => @video.id }, :remote => true %>

<%= button_to "-1", { :action => "create", :id => @video.id }, :remote => true %>
```

They both go to the create method, but I want one to set a video_votes table column named 'value' equal to 1 while the other one sets it equal to -1. Where should I do this?

Also, since I'm using AJAX with a create.js.erb file, do I need to do something like `respond_to format do format.js` in the create controller method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass an aditional paramater signifying what type of vote it is.

```
<%= button_to "+1", { :action => "create", :id => @video.id, :type => "up" }, :remote => true %>


<%= button_to "-1", { :action => "create", :id => @video.id, :type => "down" }, :remote => true %>
```

And in your def create:

```
def create

  if params[:type] == "up"
    #do this
  else
    # do that
  end

end
```

Also you will have to render the create.erb.js file.

Comment: Ahh that makes things easy. Two questions: 1. What do you mean by "render" create.js.erb? 2. How did you know that :type is a key in the params hash?

Comment: It wasn't specific to just type, you could of named it :typeabcfoobar, it didn't matter. And when I say render create.js.erb, I meant what you stated: respond_to